# Express response with Buffer as image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to return an image created from a base 64 `Buffer` from an Express endpoint, which works expected, but in `Chrome Devtools`, the type of the returned content is read as type `Document`.

[image]

```
const pixel = new Buffer(
  "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7",
  "base64"
);

app.get('/*.gif', async (request, response) => {

  try {
    const { u } = request.query;
    const { name: id } = path.parse(request.path);

    if (!u) throw new Error("No user found");
    if (!id) throw new Error("No id found");

    response.setHeader( "Content-Type", "image/gif")
    response.setHeader( "Content-Length", pixel.length,)
    response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    response.setHeader( "Content-Type", "image/gif")
    response.send(pixel);


  } catch (error) {
     response.status(400);
      return response.send(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All gif seems to be transmitted as document in chrome, just see :

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif